# React-router não renderizando páginas não encontradas corretamente

Tags: express.js, react, ejs, react-router

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando React + React-router + Express para fazer a renderização no servidor e injetando em uma view EJS.

Está funcionando corretamente, porém notei que ao não encontrar uma rota como `/naoexiste` a solicitação cai corretamente no React-router e meu componente `PaginaNaoEncontrada` é renderizado corretamente (renderização client) porém, se uma requisição como `/naoexiste/` é feita, meu componente é renderizado na versão do servidor (a qual não carregou o bundle e algumas outras coisas que são carregados no html, como estilos externos).

Será que estou deixando algo passar ?

**routes.js**

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={MainPage}>
        <IndexRoute component={Pagina}/>
        <Route path="pagina" component={Pagina}/>
        <Route path='*' component={PaginaNaoEncontrada} />
    </Route>
);
```

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}
            routes={routes}
            onUpdate={()=> window.scrollTo(0,0)}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

**Server.js** (Parte do controle de rotas, tem outras coisas mas não creio que interfiram nessa questão)

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  (0, _reactRouter.match)({ routes: _routes2.default, location: req.url }, function (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }

    if (redirectLocation) {
      return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathName + redirectLocation.search);
    }

    var markup = void 0;
    if (renderProps) {
      markup = (0, _server.renderToString)(_react2.default.createElement(_reactRouter.RouterContext, renderProps));
    } else {
      markup = (0, _server.renderToString)(_react2.default.createElement(_NotFoundPage2.default, null));
      res.status(404);
    }

    return res.render('index', { markup: markup });
  });
});
```

**Versões:**

```
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-dom": "15.4.1",
"react-router": "^3.0.0",
"ejs": "^2.5.3",
"express": "^4.12.4",
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do React Router que estás a usar?

Comment: @Sergio Editei com as versões

Comment: Acho que nas versões antigas daria para fazer `'*/?'`, já testaste isso?

Comment: @Sergio já tinha tentado com `*/` agora fiz com `*/?` mas tive o mesmo resultado :/

Comment: Acho estranho que mesmo rotas existentes acontece isso, se eu declaro a rota como `planos` e digitar `planos/`

Comment: Testa colocar `<Route path='*'` fora do componente `<Route path="/"`, algo como [neste exemplo](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/examples/route-no-match/app.js#L49-L54) da documentação.

Comment: @Sergio Fiz e deu o mesmo resultado, estou tentando redirecionar as chamadas 404 no servidor para "/pagina_nao_encontrada" ou algo do tipo mas nada feito tbm

Comment: @Sergio, descobri o que era, algo bem idiota até, ao importar o bundle não estava colocando a barra, por exemplo : `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` ao invés de `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` isso fazia com o que o servidor buscasse os arquivos no caminho que estava ao invés da raiz :/

Answer (score 0):

Consegui encontrar onde estava o erro.

**TL;DR**

> Ao importar o `bundle.js`que continha a lógica do client não estava
>   utilizando `/bundle.js` e sim `bundle.js`

Assim, por mais que o servidor fizesse o pré render da página correta a solicitação para recuperar esse bundle falhava pois ele tentava buscar no endereço atual e não a partir da raiz.

Exemplificando:

Ao chamar `http://localhost:3000/como_funciona` o servidor me devolvia o componente correto e a solicitação para o bundle acontecia a partir da raiz "`/bundle.js`", porém, ao chamar `http://localhost:3000/como_funciona/` o servidor renderizava a página correta, porém a chamada para o bundle acontecia no endereço  `http://localhost:3000/como_funciona/bundle.js` por isso não era encontrado.

Um adendo que percebi também, é que isso acontecia ao usar um `<Link to="pagina" />` ao invés de `<Link to"/pagina" />` se estiver na raiz vai tranquilo, se não ele irá concatenar com o endereço atual.